# How to remove a user session from store in Gorilla?

Tags: go, session, gorilla

Using [Gorilla session](https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions), I'd like to be able to find and invalidate a user's session from the store. The use case is when a moderator wants to kick an abusive user out immediately.

I've looked at the docs but all that I see is how to deal with requests:

```
func (s *FilesystemStore) Get(r *http.Request, name string) (*Session, error)
```

So appreciate your hint on how to find and remove a particular user's session, when only `userID` is known.

Comment: Even in that case there should be a way to find the user beford adding a `kicked` field to his cookie. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [Store API](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/v1.2.0/store.go#L22) doesn't provide a method for session removal/invalidation in the latest version at the moment (v1.2.0), though according to comment in [Save method](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/v1.2.0/store.go#L206-L209) of FilesystemStore you could force removal:

> If the Options.MaxAge of the session is <= 0 then the session file will be
> deleted from the store path. With this process it enforces the properly
> session cookie handling so no need to trust in the  cookie management in the
> web browser.

Please note, if you use another store for sessions you would need to consult its documentation.

Comment: Well, first I need to find the user's session in the store (btw I use redis as session store), then I can set `Options.MaxAge` to 0. So the main question is how can I find the session based on UserID?